# For which sequences $\{a_n\}$ is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{a_n} )^{a_n}=e$ true?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to know when I can say that

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{a_n} = e$$

Is it enough for sequence $a_n$ to be monotonic sequence than tends to infinity?

Can I somehow generalize it little further?

Comment: It is enough, sure. All you need is that $|a_n|\to\infty$.

Comment: Monotonic is not usefull, if $\lim _n a_n= +\infty$, then $1\over a_n= o(1)$,

Comment: Thank you! But, what would happen if we had limit of function $f(x)$ for $ x \rightarrow \infty$, instead of sequence limit? By that I mean: 

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \Big(1+\frac{1}{f(x)} \Big)^{f(x)} = e$$

Edit: Maybe I should edit my question to ask that, because it's what I really meant, but I am not sure if I can really change the question after posting it. It kind of doesn't seem right.