# Showing $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1+ a_n\right)^\frac{1}{a_n} = e $ by building subsequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $ (a_n) $ be a sequence s.t. $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}. a_n \neq 0 $, also suppose that  $ a_n \rightarrow 0 $. show that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1+ a_n\right)^\frac{1}{a_n} = e $

*Related ( But not exactly what I look for ):* [For which sequences $\{a_n\}$ is $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{a_n} )^{a_n}=e$ true?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1522322/for-which-sequences-a-n-is-lim-n-rightarrow-infty1-frac1a-n)

**My attempt:**
if $ a_n \rightarrow 0 $ then $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow \infty $ or $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow -\infty $ or $ \frac{1}{a_n} $ does not converge.
If $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow \infty $ then define $ b_n = \frac{1}{a_n} $ and we'll have that     $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1+ \frac{1}{b_n}\right)^{b_n} = e $ ( this is fact we can use).
[ However then I need to show the cases " $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow -\infty $ or $ \frac{1}{a_n} $ does not converge " ]

**My question:** I was told there was an easier approach - " noticing  that I can build a subsequence whose limit is either $ +\infty  $ or $ -\infty $ and then since I covered all the natural indexes by giving all the possible subsequences that converge to the same limit and so the limit of the original sequence is the same. ".
However, I couldn't really figure out how to do the proof with subsequences as I was told, can you direct me as to how to do so here please? It seems a little bit hard to think about and formulate.

**Edit**: I'm not allowed to use $ exp $ or $ ln $ manipulations. Also, for the case $ \frac{1}{a_n} \rightarrow -\infty $ I'd define $ b_n = - \frac{1}{a_n} $ and then I'd get:
$\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1- \frac{1}{b_n}\right)^{-b_n} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{e}} = e $. But I'm interested in knowing if there is an easier proof concerning subsequences.

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(1 +a_n \right) ^ { \frac{1}{a_{n}}} = \lim_{n \to\infty} \exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1 + a_n\right)}{a_n} \right)=  \lim_{h \to0} \exp\left(\frac{\ln\left(1 +h \right)}{h} \right)=e$$

Comment: I cannot use $ exp $ or $ ln $.

Comment: You know that when $a_{n}$ are all postive and if $a_{n}$ are all negative  then the sequence converges to $e$ then  you can prove that general $a_{n}$  also converges to $e$ this can be proven .

Comment: For $\frac 1{a_n} \to -\infty$, set $b_n = -\frac 1{a_n}$, and you get the same result as for $\frac 1{a_n} \to \infty$, Your hint was about handling the "does not converge" case. For that, separate $\{a_n\}$ into two subsequences, one containing all the negative entries, and the other all the positive entries. Because $a_n \to 0$, both subsequences have to diverge to $-\infty$ and $\infty$ respectively. By the previous cases, your limit must converge to $e$ in either case. Use that to show that the full sequence must also converge to $e$.